# Procedural tape in geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create A geo nodes setup that will convert curves into something like a VHS M loading system, specifically with tape wrapping over and under rollers (the convex hull trick is good for some belts but not what im going for)
[image: Something like this]

I am still relatively new to geo nodes and my (doubtlessly naive) plan was to use a drawn curve with a very low resolution as a base, then i can instance cylinders on those points, convert the curve to mesh for normal orientation, use those normals to align the cylinders to the "tape", then i can use the radius of the curves as the radius of the curve fillet and the offset of each instance, however i am encountering issues i have no idea how to resolve.
[image]

1. the cylinders offset does not align with the edges of the curve,
2. i need to figure out a way to switch the direction of the instance translation to be on the side of the curve with the smaller angle,
3. figure out what the actual math for the correct instance translation would be,

bonus points if curve radius can control the radius of each cylinder and the tape, and/or if this can work in all 3 dimensions with tilt.
any thoughts would be appreciated, thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sample nearest with beveled curve to get nearest position to create directional vector and push the points. Note that Fillet count has to be even for it to work

[image]

The more complicated solution is to manually calculate direction vector using point neighbors, calculate point angles and use with scale function to scale the vector

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1... wouldn't it be nice, since they must already be calculated internally, if _Fillet Curve_ output 'Fillet Center' , and 'Fillet Radius' (after a possible limit). (edit: UV'd on Right-Click-Select)